# Robot localization : needs a 4th sensor

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, static-map, robot-localization, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I use robot localization with 3 input sensor: IMU - Wheel_odometry - GPS_odometry using a static map from google maps.
But sometimes GPS isn't very accurate.
I use 2D lidars for detection that outputs a laser scan message to ROS navigation stack.
I want to use a set of lidars as an extra source of localization with the same static google maps.

So any help, How can I use a static map and 2D lidars to output a pose message to robot localization?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290533/robot-localization-:-needs-a-4th-sensor/) by [Mahmoud Kamel](https://answers.ros.org/users/30538/mahmoud-kamel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2018-05-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mahmoud Kamel](https://answers.ros.org/users/30538/mahmoud-kamel/) on 2018-05-15**:
Thank you , It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This topic](https://answers.ros.org/question/218137/using-robot_localization-with-amcl/)  of using robot_localization with amcl might help.

---

Originally posted by [chung](https://answers.ros.org/users/32005/chung/) with karma: 81 on 2018-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1